# How to redirect entire domain to new domain except homepage via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I have found some questions that are close to what I need, but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.

While I've worked with htaccess files in the past, it's pretty much been just copying and pasting code that is proven to work, or just doing simple 301 redirects. To be honest, I get pretty confused when looking at htaccess rewrite rules, so unfortunately are not going to be able to do from scratch. So I'm really hoping there is someone kind enough to provide a code example just using placeholder domain names.

Here is my situation. I'm doing work for a company who has split up into different divisions (4). So they want to take the site on their current domain, move it to a different domain. Then put up a simple html splash page on the old domain that provides links to the 4 different sites they will have (one of those being what was the old site on a new domain).

So I need to redirect everything from olddomain.com to newdomain.com with the exception of the homepage. Not sure if this matters, but site that was on the old domain was a WordPress site so technically is index.php. But the new site/splash page is named index.html.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need to redirect everything from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com` with the exception of the homepage.

You can use this rule in the site root .htaccess of `olddomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(css|js|images)/ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

`RewriteRule .` will match everything except the home page **just make sure this rule is the first rule** in your .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I will give this a try and let you know how it goes. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi anubhava, you're code worked perfectly. However, I didn't take into consideration that the assets for the splash page would get redirected as well. Besides the index.html page, I also have a folders for css, images and javascript. Using the code you provided, how would i also exclude those directories. Sorry for not thinking of that sooner.

Comment: See edited answer. You need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|images)/ [NC]` condition to exclude certain assets directories. (Change names of these folders as per your actual names)

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, wasn't a redirect issue. You're code works perfectly. Thanks, again.